# Numpy high precision

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, decimal

I am using numpy and pyfits to manipulate spectra and I require high precision (something like 8-10 decimal places on a value which might go as high as 10^12). For that the data type "decimal" would be perfect (float64 is not good enough), but unfortunalely numpy.interp does not like it:

```
File ".../modules/manip_fits.py", line 47, in get_shift
pix_shift = np.interp(x, xp, fp)-fp
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1053, in interp
return compiled_interp(x, xp, fp, left, right)
TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
```

A simplified version of the code I use:

```
fp = np.array(range(new_wave.shape[-1]),dtype=Decimal)
pix_shift = np.empty_like(wave,dtype=Decimal)
      x = wave
  xp = new_wave
 pix_shift = np.interp(x, xp, fp)-fp
```

where 'wave' and 'new_wave' are a one-dimension numpy array representing a 1D spectrum. This code is needed to shift my spectra along the x-axis (which is wavelenght)

My biggest issue is that further down the code I divide my spectra by a template spectrum constructed from the sum of all my spectra in order to analyse the differences and since I do not have enough decimal places I am getting rounding errors. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Test Example:

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 12

wave = np.array([Decimal(xx*np.pi) for xx in range(0,10)],dtype=np.dtype(Decimal))
new_wave = np.array([Decimal(xx*np.pi+0.5) for xx in range(0,10)],dtype=np.dtype(Decimal))

fp = np.array(range(new_wave.shape[-1]),dtype=Decimal)
pix_shift = np.empty_like(wave,dtype=Decimal)

x = wave
xp = new_wave
pix_shift = np.interp(x, xp, fp)-fp
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 16, in <module>
    pix_shift = np.interp(x, xp, fp)-fp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1053, in interp
    return compiled_interp(x, xp, fp, left, right)
TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
```

this is the closest I can provide without using the real spectra in fits format.

UPDATE 2:
Some typical values of my spectra, printed using Decimal:

```
  18786960689.118938446044921875
  18473926205.282184600830078125
  18325454516.792461395263671875
  18400241010.149127960205078125
2577901751996.03857421875
2571812230557.63330078125
2567431795280.80712890625
```

the problem I am getting is when I make operations between them, I get rounding up errors. For instance, I create a template for all spectra by summing all of them. Then I use this template to normalize every spectra. An example:

```
Spectra = np.array([Spectrum1, Spectrum2, ...])
Template = np.nansum(Spectra, axis= 0)

NormSpectra = Spectra/Template
```

This should return me only the noise on the spectra (assuming that the template is a good representation of the star). I tried normalizing each spectrum to its total flux

```
(Spectrum1 = Spectrum1/np.nansum(Spectrum1), ...)
```

as well as the template, but would get even worse rounding up errors.

Using Decimal would work fine for me, but I need to "shift" my spectra so all spectral features/lines are aligned.

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Have you tried using `numpy.longdouble` as a dtype? http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-dev/2008-March/008562.html

Comment: @Zhenya: just tried it, and I am stil gettin "TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type" :(

Comment: can you provide a small self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: "something like 8-10 decimal places on a value which might go as high as 10^12" could be problematic for float32, but it's far from the limits of float64. Can you post an example showing how float64 is not enough? You could try scaling your problem too.

Comment: Your updated code complains that conversion from a float to a Decimal is not allowed. At any rate, I agree with @jordeca that a more helpful example would be to show how  float64 is not enough. Moreover, I'd check (i) whether longdouble is not enough, and (ii) whether a problem persists if you use `scipy.interp1d` instead of `numpy.interp`.

Comment: Decimal is not a numpy dtype object or convertable to one, so you will never be able to use it as a dtype. What Numpy is doing is seeing 'oh, you provided an arbitrary class, better create a Python-Object array`. Which works okay, until you have to cast back to a NumPy datatype to do the calculation.I get a more useful error message from your code, which is `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'`. It supports this theory. I would be quite surprised if scipy.interp1d worked for this object-array you created either, since an array of..

Comment: .. since an array of dtype 'O' is not considered as a numeric type, and NumPy will not attempt to perform numeric calculations with it.

Comment: @jorgeca: I updated the post with a few typical values for my spectra. The issue comes when I try to divide each spectra by its template, getting what looks like rounding errors.

Comment: @Zhenya: I thought about that, bus since scipy uses numpy, I thought it might have the same issues? anyway, I decided to go and make my own interpolation function, I do not need anything fancy, a linear interpolation should be enough.

Comment: @kampu: hum, I understand that. So better to do my own interpolation routine in pure python and that way I can use decimal.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to reproduce your rounding errors from the data you provided. By the way, did you try whether the extra bits of `dtype=np.longdouble` are enough? Also, [mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) could be interesting for you (it's a library for multiprecision floating-point arithmetic in pure Python than can also use fast compiled backends).

Comment: @jorgeca: Hey thanks, I guess that mpmath might help :). I also was looking at the problem the wrong way: most of the time I will not need this kind of precision on my numpy operations, only when I normalize my spectra (ie, dividing stuff like 18400241010.149127960205078125 by 18786960689.118938446044921875), so I can just bypass the interp problem altogether. Thank you all for the help!!

Comment: How much significant digits has your data? Is the problem in rounding errors only? If you need less than 14 decimal significant digits, and you need precise summation, you can use Karatsuba algorithm.

Answer (score 10):

How can you be sure `np.float64`? In typical usecases, one can expect ~15 significant figures from a double.

If you are sure that this is not enough, you can try `np.float128` (aka `np.longdouble`).

**But** your problem seems deeper than that: it seems to be an ill-posed problem (division of big numbers by small numbers usually are). And this is not something you want. Increasing the precision should solve the problem to a certain extent but you will encounter some data that would require float256/float512/etc. to avoid pathological rounding errors.

I would advise you to explain your problem, not your solution so that we could hopefully find another way to solve it in every cases ([XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).